# Why there is no response?

Tags: javascript, web

It's pretty simple, but when I execute the web, there is no alert at all! I was just doing the same as a video of youtube, but there is no response when I want to do the same thing as he does.

```
// this is my html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="shiyan.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Javascript Event</h1>
</header>

<main>
<h4> Add Numbers:</h4>
<p>
  <input id = "num-one"> + <input id = "num-two">
</p>
<p id = "add-sum"></p>
</main>

<script src="shiyan.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

//here is my shiyan.js in the same file of html
var numOne = document.getElementById("num-one");
var numTwo = document.getElementById("num-two");
var addSum = document.getElementById("add-sum");

numOne.addEventListener("click ", function(){

  alert("hahahahaa");
});
```

Comment: Use `"click "` instead of  `"click"`

Comment: `"click "` is not the same as `"click"` - get rid of the space

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the stray space in `click`

```
numOne.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("hahahahaa");
});
```

Comment: @NeilMa Could you mark my answer as correct please?